# Error deploying to elastic beanstalk - Unknown job: nodejs

Tags: node.js, meteor, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying a meteor project to beanstalk application but I recieve the error:

```
Script /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/50start.sh 
failed with returncode 1
```

And in the /var/log/directory-hooks-executor.log i find:

```
status: Unknown job: nodejs
Failed to find status of job.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 599, in <module>
main()
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 583, in main
nodejs_upstart.start()
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 199, in start
raise e
Exception: Failed to run command: None
```

I'm running 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.1.0 running Node.js
Any idea of the reason?

Answer (score 6):

In my case, this error was produced when I passed a Json value as ENV variable.

This happen because Beanstalk store all env variables in the file /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#init#nodejs.conf using "".

For example:

```
METEOR_SETTINGS='{ "public": { } }'
```

will be written in nodejs.conf as

```
METEOR_SETTINGS="{ "public": { } }"
```

Since the string is not correctly closed, it will produce errors.